# how to run two or more javascript functions in <script> tag at the php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wrote the code like this, but one doesn't work if I **write two tag (script)** like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.data').DataTable();
        demo.initChartist();

    });
</script>
```

and this code in **one file**

```
 <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(function(){
        $(document).on('click','.edit-record',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
            $.post('hpegawai.php',
                {id:$(this).attr('data-id')},
                function(html){
                    $(".modal-body").html(html);
                }   
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What has this really got to do with PHP?

Comment: i mean in tag html at php file

Comment: it doesn't seem to have anything to do directly but the file that was made in PHP file but the script is HTML and javascript, I don't know in detail the working system of php.

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the error, which is because there is one line of javascript code that is error so that the code below does not work properly

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.data').DataTable();
    //demo.initChartist();// <-- the mistake 

});
```

thank you friends for all response :)